# jQuery animate() callback not working right with removeClass()

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, removeclass

Hey guys I'm working on a jQuery code snippet that's suppose to remove a class from an object after the animation has been completed. This is what I have so far:

```
$('.box').hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().addClass('active').animate({ 'margin-top': '-49px' }, 500);
    }, function() {
        $element = $(this);
        $(this).stop().animate({ 'margin-top': '0' }, 500, function() {
            $element.removeClass('active');
        });
    });
```

The problem is that sometimes when the animation completes the class is not removed. This happens when I move too fast between divs.

You can view an example [here](http://strata-solar.onwired.com.php5-1.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/) in the slider section there are three boxes inside the slider that says 'City', 'House', and 'Business'.

Any help is appreciated.

PS the same thing happens on the main navigation, sometimes the sub-nav just hangs there. Here is the code for the navigation:

```
$('#navigation ul li').hover(function(){
        $("a:eq(0)", this).addClass("hover");
        $(this).find('ul:eq(0)').stop(true, true).slideToggle();
        }, function(){
            $("a:eq(0)", this).removeClass("hover");
            $(this).find('ul:eq(0)').stop(true, true).slideToggle();
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `$element` declaration to this

```
var $element = $(this);
```

Comment: Wow that worked perfectly thanks a lot Starx! I'm curious thought why did just putting the keyword var fixed the issue?

Comment: @AntonioVitor, The reason was that $element was being received as global variable, so the problem arose. But my re-declaring $element inside using `var` insured the variable was local and only perceived by respective elements.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is probably the fact that `$element` is an implicit global variable so when multiple .box objects have hover animations going at the same time, they will step on each other's value in the global variable.  It should be `var $element = $(this)` to properly make it a local variable.  Or, the need for it can be eliminated entirely as I've shown in my suggested code below.

Also, the completion function is not called when the animation is terminated with `.stop()` so when you go really fast, you will likely stop some of your animations with `.stop()` which causes your completion functions to not get called.  Depending upon the situation this might or might not be a problem.

You may also want to visit the options you are using for `.stop()`, because often you want to at least use `.stop(true)` to not only stop the current animation, but to remove it from the queue so it isn't acted upon later.

I would suggest this implementation:

```
$('.box').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop(true).addClass('active').animate({ 'margin-top': '-49px' }, 500);
}, function() {
    $(this).stop(true).animate({ 'margin-top': '0' }, 500, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
});
```